# Executing raw sql query using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I use his code for executing `SQL query` in entity framework :

```
using (var db = new VSServicesEntities())
            {                 
                const string selectCmd = @"if exists (Select top 1 IsUserOn From ServiceMembers Where ServiceCode=@ServiceCode and Number=@Number) 
                             Select isnull(IsUserOn,0) IsON 
                             From ServiceMembers Where ServiceCode=@ServiceCode and Number=@Number
                          else 
                             Select Null IsON";
                var data = db.ServiceMembers.SqlQuery(selectCmd, number, serviceCode).ToList();
                if (data.Count()>1)
                {

                    //How to acccess value of returned column named IsON
                }
```

and i want in the if block `if (data.Count()>1)` to access value of column that returned by executing query, this column's name is `IsON`, how can i access to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are expecting a list of entities, then you will need to determine which one you want with `.First()`, `.Single()` or a similar function.

From there it should be a simple case of writing `var result = data.First().IsON;` to get your value from that column, or something similar. This is the way I do it, you will get an exception if the entity isn't known or the column from the table isn't known either. But from what you have provided, it shouldn't be an issue.